# Working with meshgrid in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How would you replace the following by meshgrid?

```
N=.33;
P=.45;

for i =1:10
    for j=1:20
        x0=i+N;
        y0=j+P;
        f(i,j)=exp(x0+y0);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

I think something like

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:10, 1:20);
Z = exp( (X+N) + (Y+P) );
% surf(X, Y, Z);
```

read [here](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/meshgrid.html)

**edit**

as user requested (if I've understood well):

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:10, 1:20);
X1 = X + N; Y1 = Y + P; 
Z = exp( X1 + Y1 );
% surf(X1, Y1, Z);
```